# ParserError: Expected ',' but got identifier

Tags: solidity, remix, events, struct, error

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.0 <0.7.0;

contract NewHello{

    struct kullanicilar{
        string name;
        string surname;
        uint age;
    }

    event infoChanged(
        string name,
        string surname,
        uint age
    );

    uint newUser;
    mapping(address => string) public users; // contains a name for every address
    //[] public userAddress ;

    function updateUser(string memory name , string memory surname , unit age) public returns(uint userID){
        userID = newUser++;
        users[userID] = kullanicilar(string name, string surname, age);
        emit infoChanged(name,surname,age);
    }
    function getUser(address a) public view returns(string memory) {
        return users[a]; // return address name
    }
}
```

Hello ! I want to tell you what I want.
I built a sturct name is kullanıcılar(means users in Turkish) and I built a event for if I changed my informations about my users I want to see my event.
finally I made getUser func which is return to me the name of this user.

but I have got a error at updateUser function which is

> ***ParserError: Expected ',' but got identifier users[userID] = kullanicilar(string name, string surname, age); ^--^***

I checked my codes and I can't find my error anyone can help me for this :)
thanks for read :)

Comment: Your code contains lots of simple mistakes please refer first solidity tutorial to avoid this type of simple mistakes.

Comment: whats your advise for me ? can you give me a example of theese tutorial please

Comment: you can refer official doc of solidity. https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.5.10/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

heyyy I found my answer guys :) 
thanks for the contribution

the answer is  just chance the mapping and forget the getUser function.

code is :

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.0 <0.7.0;
```

contract NewHello{

```
struct user{
    string name;
    string surname;
    uint age;
}

event infoChanged(
    string name,
    string surname,
    uint age
);

uint newUser;
mapping(uint => user) public users; // contains a name for every address
//[] public userAddress ;

function updateUser(string memory name , string memory surname , uint age) public returns(uint userID){
    userID = newUser++;
    users[userID] = user(name, surname, age);

    emit infoChanged(name,surname,age);
}
//function getUser(uint a) public view returns(string memory) {
//    return users[a]; // return address name
//}
```

}

Answer (score 4):

You should not specify the types of parameters when you pass them in a function-call:

```
users[userID] = kullanicilar(string name, string surname, age);
```

Change it to:

```
users[userID] = kullanicilar(name, surname, age);
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @goodvibration, [you do not need to specify the types of the **struct members** when you declare a new `struct` *"instance"*](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.5.10/types.html#structs) ( new struct instance = new variable of type `struct`).

> Because the type is already specified in your initial struct
>   definition

This is why the compiler returns an error message : Basically, the Solidity compiler expects a string value (either as a variable, or directly hardcoded string into your argument, like `"John Doe"`). So it consider the first `string` keyword as the value.

```
Expected , but got identifier :
users[userID] = kullanicilar(string name, string surname, age);
                                    ^--^
```

---

## How to declare a Struct in Solidity ?

Let's go back to your example :

```
struct User {
    string name;
    string surname;
    uint age;
}

// Rename `newUser` by `total_users`
// uint newUser;
uint total_users;

mapping(uint => User) public users;
```

Before you might consider the following :

1. According to the Solidity documentation, [the naming convention for `struct` is to use CapWords.](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.5.10/style-guide.html#struct-names). So it would look nicer (for reading purpose) to use **U**ser, instead of `user`.
2. Since you are using `newUser++` (to add a new user I suppose), you should rename your function `setUser` and not `updateUser`.
3. [You can't loop through a mapping](https://forum.ethereum.org/discussion/1995/iterating-mapping-types). So you should implement 1) an array on top, and 2) a variable `total_users` as an index that increments when you add a new user. 
   Like the [**Campaign** contract example from the Solidity doc](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.5.10/types.html#structs), look at the `newCampaign` function.

Back to the subject !

> #### You have three ways in Solidity to implement a custom `struct` into a variable :

---

### The conventional way

```
function setUserMethod1(string memory _name , string memory _surname , uint _age) public returns(uint userID){
    userID = total_users++;
    User memory new_user;
    new_user.name = _name;
    new_user.surname = _surname;
    new_user.age = _age;

    users[userID] = new_user;

    emit infoChanged(_name,_surname,_age);
}
```

Firstly, you create an empty **User** `struct` that you store in memory. Secondly, You assign your parameters to the struct member via **3 separate instructions**. Finally, you assign your `new_user` (stored in memory) as the value for the key you specified in your mapping.

***Transaction cost :*** 93975 
***Execution cost :*** 71039

---

### The readable way

```
function setUserMethod2(string memory _name , string memory _surname , uint _age) public returns(uint userID) {
    userID = total_users++;
    users[userID] = User({
        name: _name,
        surname: _surname,
        age: _age
    });
    emit infoChanged(_name,_surname,_age);
}
```

> I personally think this is the most readable (*Javascript like*) and
>   efficient way (2 lines of code removed).

You simply 1) point to a key in the mapping (Using your newly generated `userID`) and 2) Creating the `struct` directly in the value assignment.

The parentheses `()` of **User** instantiate the Struct [(like you instantiate a Javascript object)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Objects_and_properties) and the `{}` contain the members of your `struct`.

You then specify you function parameters for each specific member (Note that you use colons `:` for `Struct Member -> Value` assignment, [like you would do for an object in Javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Using_object_initializers)

***Transaction cost*** : 93786
***Execution cost*** : 70914

---

### The shorter way

```
function setUserMethod3(string memory _name , string memory _surname , uint _age) public returns(uint userID) {
    userID = total_users++;
    users[userID] = User(_name, _surname, _age);
    emit infoChanged(_name,_surname,_age);
}
```

This is the shorter way to initialise your custom `struct` type variable. With a syntax [similar to a constructor function in Javascript.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Using_a_constructor_function).

Since the struct members are not mentioned, it's a bit harder to guess (might need to scroll back up to the `struct` definition to understand which value is assigned to which member.

***Transaction cost*** : 93806
***Execution cost*** : 70870

---

*Hope it helps :)*

Comment: Just for clarifying, the gas cost of methods 2 and 3 is less because you are calling this functions after method 1 in the same contract, so when you call methods 2 and 3 the storage is not empty. The correct way to see that is to deploy a new contract for each method execution, then you will see that the gas cost is practically the same.

Comment: @alberto thanks for the clarification. I did not notice that.
Doing that with a non-empty storage there is exactly a 15,000 gas difference.
For method 1, where storage is empty / not empty, tx cost = 108975 / 93975 and execution cost = 86039 / 71039. Not sure, but I believe it is 15,000 refundable gas when you reset a storage value to zero ([see `SCLEAR` in the Ethereum Yellow paper appendix](https://ethereum.github.io/yellowpaper/paper.pdf))

Comment: @CJ42 The 15,000 gas difference is because the variable `total_users` initially is empty, so the gas cost will be 20,000 for setting a non-zero value from zero. Next time you call the function, `total_users` is not empty, so the gas cost will be 5,000 for setting a non-zero value from non-zero. You can debug this process to check it.